# How can I run :substitute on only part of the line and not all of it?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I have a line like this one:

```
function my_function(argument, another argument, but there are spaces)
```

I want to substitute the space characters (inside the argument's names) with underscore. I thus would like to use :

```
:s/\ /_/g
```

but how can I choose not to apply it to the whole line, but starting from, say, the cursor position ? (Or the third word) ?

Comment: In a regex, to describe the current cursor position you can use the atom `\%#`. So, you could use: `:s/\v(%#.*)@<= /_/g`. Which could be described as a space preceded by (`@<=`) characters after the cursor position.

Comment: You and Statox both proposed the `\%#` trick, I'll accept his answer if you don't write one... But could either of you explain the regexp with a bit more explicitly ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the following solution:

First use <kbd>v$</kbd> to select the text from the cursor to the end of the line. Then use the following command:

```
:s/\%V\ /_/g
```

The `\%V` indicate to change the text in the previously visually selected area, see [`:h /\%V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%V).

If I take your example:

```
function my_function(argument, another argument, but there are spaces)
```

If my cursor is on the 40th column and I use the command I just wrote I get:

```
function my_function(argument, another argument,_but_there_are_spaces)
```

---

In answer to your comment you can also use

- `\%#` which matches from the cursor position
- `\%>23c` which matches after the 23rd column.
- `\%>'m` which matches after the position of a mark

See [`:h /\%#`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%#), [`:h /\%>c`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%>c) and [`:h /\%>'m`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%>%27m).

@User9433424 gave a way to use `\%#` in his comment. For the pattern with the mark you can set it wit <kbd>ma</kbd> and then use:

```
:s/\%>'a /_/g
```

---

An explanation of the pattern given by @User9433424 is the following:

```
:s/\v(%#.*)@<= /_/
:s/                    substitution command
   \v                  Enable the very magic mode
      %#.*             Any characters from the cursor position
           @<=         Check for matches just before what follows
              space    Followed by a space
               /_/     Substitute the matches by underscores
```

You'll want to see [`:h \v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#%5Cv) and [`:h /\@<=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@<=)

Comment: It works fine ! But I'm not really used to visual selections and the whole process seems a little "heavy"... Do you think there could be something quicker ?

Comment: Yes let me update my answer :)

Comment: User9433424 gave this hint just before you, but you answered so I'm going to accept your answer if that's okay -- could you maybe explain the regexp pattern he uses a little more ? I'm still struggling with this...

Comment: I tried to make the answer as clear as possible but if @User9433424 writes his own answer don't hesitate to accept it.

Comment: Very nice explanation of the regexp, thank you ! And thanks for your comment on whose answer to accept :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use look behind (`:h \@<=`) to make sure there is a preceding '(',
and an end-of-word boundary (`:h \>`) to make sure the substitution happens where you want it.

So, with the text:

```
function my_function(argument, another argument, but there are spaces)
```

running the command:

```
:s/\((.*\)\@<=\> /_/g
```

will produce:

```
function my_function(argument, another_argument, but_there_are_spaces)
```

This might be easier than having to position the cursor each time, provided the substitution always has a known starting point.

Comment: The substitution does not always have a known starting point : it was only to... correct a weird series of typo I made. But your answer is nonetheless interesting, thanks !